# Proving non zero mutually perpendicular vectors are linearly independent - question gives me scalar product is positive definite, is that needed?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been given by the question that the scalar product is positive
definite ($\ge 0$ always - and $\langle v,v\rangle >0 \text{ for } v\ne 0$) (is
there a LaTeX way for scalar products, that doesn't look
great). **This is wrong, doesn't change anything though**

If I use this I side-step something that throws me off, I want to do
the thing I'd happily avoid - because I'm avoiding it because I'm
uncertain (that's a weird sentence).

Anyway, assume $v_1,...,v_n$ are mutually perpendicular, non-zero
vectors (by this I mean $\langle v_i,v_j \rangle=0\iff i\ne j$). I
wish to prove they are linearly independent (it's surprising how far I
have I have gotten without using this theorem).

I went for contradiction, suppose they are linearly dependent, then
$\exists a_i \ne 0$ for $\sum a_iv_i=0$

Suppose without loss of generality (fancy way of saying "reorder to
make this true") $v_1\ne 0$, then:
$$v_1=\frac{-a_2}{a_1}v_2+...+\frac{-a_n}{a_1}v_n$$

Now consider $\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle$ (should I use $v_k$ with $k\ne
1$ rather than $v_2$? I'm proving by contradiction, any would work, I
chose 2 so I could use $...$s neatly.)

$$\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle
=\langle \frac{-a_2}{a_1}v_2+...+\frac{-a_n}{a_1}v_n,v_2 \rangle
=\frac{-a_2}{a_1}\langle v_2,v_2 \rangle+\cdots
+\frac{-a_n}{a_1}\langle v_n,v_2 \rangle$$

This is where I paused and chose to ask, if I use
positive-definite-ness(?) then:
$$\frac{-a_2}{a_1}\langle v_2,v_2 \rangle\le 0$$
(oh wait that's absolute rubbish, I was thinking "I cannot think of
any positive definite scalar products"!)

**Back on track** I want to say "by hypothesis $\langle v_k,v_2
\rangle=0$ for $k\ge 3$" then:
$$\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle=\frac{-a_2}{a_1}\langle v_2,v_2
\rangle+\cdots+\frac{-a_n}{a_1}\langle v_n,v_2 \rangle
=\frac{-a_2}{a_1}\langle v_2,v_2 \rangle$$

This is where I am stuck, I am not sure I can say "by hypothesis"
because I'm assuming (part of it) isn't true.

I'm also stuck because even if I use the positive-definite part to say
$\langle v_2,v_2 \rangle >0$ I don't know that $a_2\ne 0$. I'm not
very confident with proof by contradiction because I'm assuming the
thing I know about to be false.

I *think* that if things are lin. dependent (for non-zero vectors)
then there exists **at least 2** coefficients that are non zero, one
to take the sum away from 0, and another dependent vector to bring it
back to zero. Geometrically I am not certain about this.

I'd love some help, I'm quite muddled.

Comment: The LaTeX for scalar products is `\langle` and `\rangle`, as in $\langle v, w \rangle$.

Comment: @RyanReich I wont fix them but I will remember (the answer is a lot shorter than I thought), thanks. May I also ask how to write norms? (like: $||v||$) and underline things, or put them in bold (without \boldtext I think it is, 11 characters to make 1 bold is not worth it!)

Comment: For norms: `\lVert` and `\rVert`, for bold: `\textbf{}` or `\mathbf{}` for text or for math. For underline: `\underline{}`, of course, though that one has some annoying problems.  If you think the commands are too long, you can always make a shortcut: `\newcommand*\norm[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}`.

Comment: I fixed it for you.

Comment: @RyanReich thanks, you shouldn't have had to do that.

Comment: No problem: cut and paste, find and replace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose 
$$
\lambda_1 v_1+\dotsb+\lambda_n v_n=\mathbf 0\tag{1}
$$
Applying $\langle-,v_j\rangle$ to $(1)$ gives
$$
\lambda_j\langle v_j,v_j\rangle=0\tag{2}
$$
Moreover, $\langle v_j,v_j\rangle\neq0$ since $\langle v_k,v_l\rangle=0$ if and only if $k\neq l$. Thus $(2)$ implies $\lambda_j=0$. Hence
$$
\lambda_1=\dotsb=\lambda_n=0
$$
so $v_1,\dotsc,v_n$ are linearly independent.

Comment: That bit about "applying $<-,v_j>$ to (1), can you just do that? I'm guessing it's $<\text{LHS},v_j>=<\text{RHS},v_j>$ applied like that?

Comment: @AlecTeal Yes exactly. Explicitly, $\langle \lambda_1 v_1+\dotsb+\lambda_n v_n,v_j\rangle=\langle \mathbf 0,v_j\rangle$